# Is there anyway to execute codes outside the if-else statement in java?

Tags: java, if-statement, methods, integer

*edited
Is there any way to execute codes outside the if-else statement in java?
Make the if-else statement will take the code and amount before the if-statement, and execute it.
Like from this:

```
double tax = 0;
    
if (status ==0) {
        int taxincome0 = 8350;
        int taxincome1 = 33950;
        double taxrate0 = (taxincome0 * 0.10);
        double taxrate1 = ((taxincome1 - taxincome0) * 0.15);
        
        if (income <= taxincome0){
            tax = income * 0.10;
        }
        
        else if (income <= taxincome1){
            tax = taxrate0 + (income - 8350) *0.15;
        }
    }

else if (status ==1) {
            int taxincome0 = 16700;
            int taxincome1 = 67900;
            double taxrate0 = (taxincome0 * 0.10);
            double taxrate1 = ((taxincome1 - taxincome0) * 0.15);       
            if (income <= taxincome0){
                tax = income * 0.10;
            }
            
            else if (income <= taxincome1){
                tax = taxrate0 + (income - 8350) *0.15;
}
}
```

To this:

```
double tax = 0;
    int taxincome0 = 0;
    int taxincome1 = 0;
    double taxrate0 = (taxincome0 * 0.10);
    double taxrate1 = ((taxincome1 - taxincome0) * 0.15);
    
    if (status ==0) {
        taxincome0 = 8350;
        taxincome1 = 33950;

        if (income <= taxincome0){
            tax = income * 0.10;
        }
                
        else if (income <= taxincome1){
            tax = taxrate0 + (income - 8350) *0.15;
        }
        }

    else if (status ==1) {
        
        taxincome0 = 16700;
        taxincome1 = 67900;
        
        if (income <= taxincome0){
            tax = income * 0.10;
        }
        
        else if (income <= taxincome1){
            tax = taxrate0 + (income - taxincome0) *0.15;
        }
```

Make the if-else statement will direct capture the
`double taxrate1 = ((taxincome1 - taxincome0) * 0.15);`

*update
I have tried to declare it before entering the if-else statement, and it will display the wrong calculation but no error popping out

As in Filing Status:0
Taxable income: 100000
The correct tax calculation should be 21720.0
But my code shows 4970.000000000001

Comment: As `taxincome0` and `taxincome1` are declared inside the then-block of the if-statement, both variables are not valid outside, so your second code snippet will not compile.In java, local variables are always "scoped" to the surrounding block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put the code outside of if-else statement. Even you can define all variables outside of *if-else*. The question you should do is if you need that the variables exists outside of *if-else*.

If you only will use the variables inside of if-else you should declare it inside for reduce the consum memory.

```
double tax = 0;
double taxrate0 = (taxincome0 * 0.10);
double taxrate1 = ((taxincome1 - taxincome0) * 0.15);
/*
The integer and double shows 2009 U.S. Federal Personal Tax Rates
It might have change every year by different amount and different Tax Rates
Program
*/

int taxincome0 = 8350;
int taxincome1 = 33950;

if (status ==0) {
    
    if (income <= taxincome0){
        tax = income * 0.10;
    }
    
    else if (income <= taxincome1){
        tax = taxrate0 + (income - 8350) *0.15;
    }
}
```

*after updated by user

```
} else if (income <= taxincome1) {
    /* Value of income in this moment is 0. You are doing 0 - 8350 */
    tax = taxrate0 + (income - 8350) *0.15;
}
}
```

**IT SHOULD WORK:**

```
double tax = 0;
int taxincome0 = 8350;
int taxincome1 = 33950;
double taxrate0 = (taxincome0 * 0.10);
double taxrate1 = ((taxincome1 - taxincome0) * 0.15);

if (status == 0) {
    if (income <= taxincome0) {
       tax = income * 0.10;
   } else if (income <= taxincome1) {
    tax = taxrate0 + (income - 8350) *0.15;
   }
```

}

Comment: May i ask what if i need to declare it each in multiple if-else statement? such as: 
double tax = 0;
double taxrate0 = (taxincome0 * 0.10);
double taxrate1 = ((taxincome1 - taxincome0) * 0.15);
if (status ==0) {
    
//int taxincome is the amount of taxable income
int taxincome0 = 8350;
int taxincome1 = 33950;
      
if (income <= taxincome0){
tax = income * 0.10;
}
}
  
else if (status ==1) {
      
//int taxincome is the amount of taxable income
int taxincome0 = 16700;
int taxincome1 = 67900;
      
if (income <= taxincome0){
tax = income * 0.10;
}
}

Comment: Is there not a problem if you want to declare multiple variables in multiple if-else. If the variables are the same, you can declare once outside if-else and you can use it in each if-else. I hope I'm answering to your question.

Comment: Hi, i have tried to declare it before entering the statement, but it display the wrong calculation. Could you have a check for my code i out in this post after *update?

Comment: Hi, it will work but i have to declare it to else if (status ==1), and in the taxincome0&1 amount will change in the status 1. How should i declare it as well?